# Can't load Picasso into project

Tags: java, android, picasso

```
I've added the following to my application build.gradle:

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

And when I try to use the following code, Picasso is red. It says that it cannot resolve the symbol.

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
    .load(profilePictureURL)
    .resize(50, 50) // Your preferred size
    .centerCrop()
    .into(finalHolder.profilePicture);
```

What else can I possibly do?

Comment: Have you tried doing clean and build?

Comment: Yes with no luck.

Comment: sync once again with the latest dependency and clean the and rebuild the project app.check here..http://square.github.io/picasso/   or try to add the jar instead of dependency to gradle..

Comment: Do you check your project's builld.gradle file ? it must have the specified repository like maven or jcenter. If both doesn't work download and install .jar file.

Comment: Have you imported Picasso in the java file you try to reference it?

Comment: Adding it as a JAR worked. Not sure what was wrong with my build gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Picasso. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).